# How to get jQuery Visual Studio 2010 IntelliSense to work inside a noconflict wrapper

Tags: intellisense, jquery

I added the vsdoc jquery reference in my js file:

```
/// <reference path="../jquery-1.4.1.vsdoc.js" />
```

This works fine, but once I write *inside* a no conflict wrapper...

```
(function ($) {

...here...

})(jQuery);
```

...IntelliSense does not work.

Why is this, and is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 10):

Try adding the <param /> tag at the beginning of your wrapper function:

```
/// <reference path="../jquery-1.4.1.vsdoc.js" />
(function($) { /// <param name="$" type="jQuery" />

...

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Fantastic! The `/// <param />` magic was what I needed to make this finally work for me.

Answer (score 1):

For Visual Studio 2008 when I write

```
/// <reference path="../jquery-1.4.1.vsdoc.js" />
<intellisense works here>    
(function ($) { /// <param name="$" type="jQuery" />
     <intellisense doesn't work here>
})(jQuery);
```

Does uhleeka's answer work in VS2010 and not in 2008?  Was there an update to 2010 that changes the params taken?

Edit: I should clarify, it kind of works inside the no wrapper but not completely.
Outside of the wrapper I can intellisense $.getJSON, inside I can't.  Outside after I close my selector (e.g., $('#test'). a list pops up starting with _load, inside the wrapper after I close the selector no list comes up.  Just a few examples of the different behavior.

Does anyone have advice for consistent functionality in regards to no conflict wrappers?

Answer (score 0):

```
/// <reference path="../jquery-1.4.1.js" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you work with jQuery() instead of $() intellisense works with no problems.

```
jQuery("#con").click ....
var element = jQuery(this)....
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your jquery intellisense reference files are the first items in your script file.

If you have a comment before your reference line it will not work as in

File: 
    blah
    **

Do this  
File: 

    "  
    blah

Answer (score 0):

use `/// <param name="$" type="jQuery" />` within the closure as its first line.

it worked for me in Visual Studio 2010 SP1.