# VS2012 Intellisense jQuery.noConflict()

Tags: javascript, jquery, reference, visual-studio-2012, intellisense

Here is my modified ending to the `jquery 1.6.4` file:

```
...

    // Expose jQuery to the global object
    window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;

})(window);

var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

`jQuery.intellisense.js` also exists in the same directory.

My `_references` file look like this:

```
/// <reference path="Libraries/JQuery.js" />
```

But only `$(` appears in the intellisense list and gives me tooltips for parameters, typing `$j(` doesn't appear in the list or have tooltips. Is the intellisense not seeing the `noConflict()` bit?

Comment: I suppose your question was answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3625363/how-to-get-jquery-visual-studio-2010-intellisense-to-work-inside-a-noconflict-wr).